# Twilio array of numbers from MySQL table - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, twilio

I am using this library from Twilio to send multiple numbers SMS.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/sending-via-rest

I have a mysql database and a table (called contacts) with the following attributes:
1. Name
2. Number

Instead of using a For While loop and read the full script for each number, I want to use an array as shown in the above link.

How do I make an array in [PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) with the data pulled in from the table instead of a manual insert?

From Twilio

```
  var people = new Dictionary<string,string>() { 
    {"+14158675309","Curious George"},
    {"+14158675310","Boots"},
    {"+14158675311","Virgil"}
};
```

My code

```
$sql = "SELECT * from contacts";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
var people = new Dictionary<string,string>() { 
    mysql_fetch_array($result)
};
```

I need numbers and names associated within the array.

Comment: Do not use mysql_* functions they are deprecated. Instead use mysqli_* or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

why not :

```
$sql = "SELECT * from contacts";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

var people = new Dictionary<string,string>()
for each($result as $contact)
{
    //Add  $contact['Name'], $contact['Number'] to dictionary.

    //or if you use an array instead of a dictionary.
    // $tab['number']=$contact['Number'];
    // $tab['name']=$contact['Name'];
    // array_push($people,$tab);
} 
return $people;
```

?